# Different grid settings per document or save grid settings alongside image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm working with a couple of different images/files simultaneously, switching in between them. Using a grid for measurements is fairly important (or at the very least extremely useful). However, to adjust the grid, I always have to go open Edit->Preference->Grid and remember the measurements (which for now is done by just having a note in the file).

Is there a way to save the grid settings on a per-document basis? Or any quicker way to switch between grid settings?

Answer (score 1):

Preferences can't be applied on a per document basis.

Perhaps you might want to consider using a guide layout instead. Guides are saved on a per document basis. To use it click on  *View > New Guide Layout* to access it.

[image]